# Extending the DateTime object with a set timezone

Tags: php, design-patterns, datetime

I'm having trouble on what pattern I should use to accomplish this

```
class DateTimeReference {
    function __construct($time) {
        $this = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));

    }
}

$date = new DateTime("now");                // in server time
$dateref = new DateTimeReference("now");    // in UTC
```

Basically I want to create an "extension" of the `DateTime` object but with a set timezone. Of course, this is an error because you can't re-assign `$this`. I don't want to make use of a factory object--can anyone recommend me on how I could approach this (or what pattern to use, with an example?). Possibly the decorator pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this would fit the patterns you want to use but it should work.

```
class DateTimeReference extends DateTime {
    function __construct(string $time = "now" , DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ) {
        parent::__construct($time, new DateTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
}
```

or if you want the user to be able to overwrite timezone but default to UTC if not set:

```
class DateTimeReference extends DateTime {
    function __construct(string $time = "now" , DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ) {
        parent::__construct($time,  is_null($timezone) ?  new DateTimeZone("UTC") : $timezone );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you just do:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Depends on what else your app does, but if you can do this this is the simplest :-)

Comment: You can. If you do this, the default timezone for the DateTime object will now be UTC, which is basically what your code is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem doing this..

```
class DateTimeReference extends DateTime {
    function __construct($time, $timezone) {
        parent::__construct($time);
        $this->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    }
}

$dateref = new DateTimeReference("now", "America/New_York");
```

You can also make the timezone optional via:

```
class DateTimeReference extends DateTime {
    function __construct($time, $timezone = "America/New_York") {
        parent::__construct($time);
        $this->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
    }
}

$dateref = new DateTimeReference("now");
```

Also, you can simply pass a new DateTimeZone object to DateTime's constructor:

```
$dateref = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone("America/New_York"));
```

See the examples section: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: This doesn't work because you're redefining the constructor. But I don't want to have to pass the `DateTimeZone` object everytime to the constructor, which is the point of `DateTimeReference`

Comment: In the first example, you don't pass a DateTimeZone object, you pass a string that defines the timezone you want to work with. You can set a default if you'd like to make the timezone optional. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.